# Bóton de atrás en el título de la activity

Tags: java, android

Quiero mostrar la típica flecha de atrás en una actividad y que al hacer click sobre ella me lleve a la actividad anterior (he cargado una actividad nueva con el típicon startActivity(intent). He leído que con:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Sale la flecha en el toolbar pero al hacer click no ocurre nada.

¿A alguién se le ocurre una solución?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo

Answer (score 7):

### Método 1 onSupportNavigateUp()

Si solo quieres capturar cuando se realiza una pulsación al botón de atrás en el `ActionBar` se puede con el evento `onSupportNavigateUp`

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return false;
}
```

### Método 2 onOptionsItemSelected()

Debes capturar el evento `onOptionsItemSelected`así poder realizar lo que quieras cuando se pulse la `flecha atrás` usando el identificador `android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

### Método 3 android:parentActivityName

Se puede definir un `Activity` de regreso al realizar la acción regresar, pulsando el botón atrás físico o bien el bóton atrás de la barra del titulo.

Nota: Cuando se regresa a la actividad padre se recarga de nuevo con ese método.

Con la propiedad `android:parentActivityName` se especifica la `Activity`.
También se puede especificar con el `meta-data` en el `manfiest.xml` donde se encuentra la asignación de la actividad se le puede asignar su actividad padre.

```
<activity
    android:name=".OtherActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_other_activity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**Opcional**
Si se captura la pulsación del botón con el evento `onOptionsItemSelected` para delegar la acción natural debemos usar `NavUtils`

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si extiene tu clase de ActionBarActivity puedes usar el Toolbar como un ActionBar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

para que muestre la flecha realiza lo siguiente:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Si no extiendes de ActionBarActivity, define un icono, en este caso la imagen de una flecha.

```
miActionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_flecha_back));
```

y define un OnclickListener para que realice la acción de regresar:

```
miActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       //regresar...
        finish();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Como menciona Max Sandoval. son solo dos cosas:

**En tu activity:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**En tu AndroidManifest:**

agrega el atributo **android:parentActivityName** y la **meta-data** en la actividad hijo (donde estará el boton de regresar), un ejemplo  seria:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ChildActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_child"               
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"            
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">            
    <meta-data                  
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

En `AndroidManifest.xml` debes incluir en la actividad donde vas a poner el volver:

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainFragment"
```

En la actividad

```
//Appbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

`