# ¿Como ejecutar la acción del botón BACK con cualquier otro botón en Android?

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo puedo realizar la misma acción del botón back, pero hacerlo con cualquier otro botón de la interfaz? por ejemplo, digamos que tengo una actividad y desde ahí entro a otra actividad que se queda en segundo plano, al momento de presionar el botón de back me regresa a la actividad anterior, pero yo quiero hacer eso sin presionar el botón back, quiero que eso lo haga un botón el cual yo hice en la aplicación.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En caso de que quieras realizar la acción en un activity, ya tienes tu función de onBackPressed presente en tu código. Ahora es momento de pasarla a otro botón. Asi que hacemos lo siguiente:

```
 Button MyOnBackButton = (Button) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.myid);
    MyOnBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
            //Añade más funcionalidades
        }
    });
```

En caso de que quisieses añadir alguna funcionalidad extra al método, deberías realizar lo siguiente:

Haz un @Override al metodo de onBackPressed() en tu Activity de la siguiente manera:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // Añade más funciones si fuese necesario
     super.onBackPressed();  // Invoca al método
}
```

Finalmente, en caso de que quieras realizar esta acción desde un Fragment tendrás que instanciar tu contexto(activity) y llamar el método desde ahí. Siendo algo como esto:

```
mActivity.onBackPressed();
```

Ya esta! Copia este código a tu app y todo debería funcionar correctamente.

Un saludo!

Comment: Muchas Gracias el funcionó perfecto ;) soy nuevo en esto y no se com darte una valoración pero muchas gracias mi aplicación ya hace lo que yo deseaba.

Answer (score 4):

llama al método de [**`onBackPressed();`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) :)

Comment: Sugiero que le coloques un ejemplo para que sea una respuesta muy enriquecida :), porque si no van a empezar a agregar respuestas  con la misma información. ;)

Comment: Gracias era algo sencillo pero no encontraba la manera, al llamar al método funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Por ejemplo si quieres que un botón en la barra de opciones sea para ir atrás.

Mirate: [Bóton de atrás en el título de la activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8387/b%C3%B3ton-de-atr%C3%A1s-en-el-t%C3%ADtulo-de-la-activity)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al dar clic cualquier boton, llama el método [**onBackPressed()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) por ejemplo usando el método [onKeyDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) detectas el clic de la tecla y ejecutas `onBackPressed()` :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      Log.i("Ejemplo", "Se dio clic en la tecla: " + keyCode + " y se ejecutara onBackPressed()");

      onBackPressed();

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes crear el constructor de la siguiente manera:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}
```

Posteriormente dentro del constructor, debes poner el siguiente código:

```
Button anteriorrrr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
anteriorrrr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

El botón llamado `anteriorrrr` solo se declara en este lugar, tal cual como está en el código, por lo tanto no hay necesidad de volver a hacerlo.