# boton regresar Toolbar a la anterior activity " sin Recargar de nuevo el Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

Tengo este código en el AndroidManifest.xml pero al presionar el boton de ir Atras, me recarga el activity y como tengo una consulta esta se vuelve a generar, haciendo el proceso un poco tardado.

codigo del AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Noticias"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

La Pregunta es... Existe otra manera de Regresar a un Activity si que este se vulva a cargar?

Comment: Si buscas un poco, ya se ha tratado varias veces esa feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes eliminar lo de `AndriodManifest.xml` te quede así:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Noticias">
</activity>
```

Para poner botón atrás a la `ActionBar` [Bóton de atrás en el título de la activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8390/2230)

Si quieres detectar su pulsación [¿Como ejecutar la acción del botón Back con cualquier otro botón en Android Studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10206/2230)

Tutorial de patrón de navegación entre actividades: [Cómo volver atrás de una actividad en android](http://codrspace.com/webserveis/como-volver-atras-activity-android/)